# Convert enter to tab in windows mobile

Tags: javascript, ie-mobile

Have the following piece of javascript over on http://jsfiddle.net/mhenrixon/zPLgS/16/ and its working fine in regular browsers but I can't make it work in IE Mobile for Windows CE 6.0 where it needs to work. Anyone knows how to fix that?

```
function tab(field, event) {
    if (event.which == 13 /* IE9/Firefox/Chrome/Opera/Safari */ || event.keyCode == 13 /* IE8 and earlier */ ) {
        for (i = 0; i < field.form.elements.length; i++) {
            if (field.form.elements[i].tabIndex == field.tabIndex + 1) {
                field.form.elements[i].focus();
                if (field.form.elements[i].type == "text") {
                    field.form.elements[i].select();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys the problem was not getting the key and it was not changing propagation or anything like that it was actually quite easy.

Full solution

```
function tab(field, event) {
  if (event.which == 13 /* IE9/Firefox/Chrome/Opera/Safari */ || event.keyCode == 13  /* IE8 and earlier */) {
    nextElement(field);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function nextElement(field) {
  for (var i = 0; i < field.form.elements.length; i++) {
    if (field.form.elements[i].tabIndex == field.tabIndex + 1) {
      field.form.elements[i].focus();
      if (field.form.elements[i].type == "text") {
        field.form.elements[i].select();
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you were to just change the `event.which` or `event.keyCode` from `ENTER` to `TAB`, and let the default behavior go through? Something like:

```
function tab(event) {
    if (event.which && event.which == 13)
        event.which = 9;
    else if (event.keyCode && event.keyCode == 13)
        event.keyCode = 9;
}
```

Not sure if they key codes are different for Windows Mobile, but to figure that out all you need to do is `alert(event.which);` or `alert(event.keyCode);`.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot test any of these links because I dont have any mobile device with Windows Mobile but maybe there is something helpful for you:

- [Another post with same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561782/capturing-the-enter-key-on-textbox-in-asp-net-for-windows-ce)
- [A workaround](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/819760-capture-enter-key)
- [KeyCodes MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb431750.aspx)
- [Another helpful link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17241/Capturing-the-Enter-key-to-cause-a-button-click)